# MySQL Select * FROM table WHERE a column's (JSON Object) specific value's string length is <1

Tags: mysql, json, select

I need to return all records from a table where the submission column has an empty 'email' value in the JSON object. The query should only return records 15 and 17 from the table below.

```
 +------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
 | id | name               | submission                               |
 +------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
 | 13 | Chris Sale         | {"gender":"m"},{"email":"xyz@abc.com"}   |  
 | 14 | Amy Verlander      | {"gender":"f"},{"email":"123@abc.com"}   |  
 | 15 | CC Sabathia        | {"gender":"f"},{"email":""}              |  
 | 16 | Sonny Grey         | {"gender":"m"},{"email":"nko@abc.com"}   |  
 | 17 | Jen Chapman        | {"gender":"m"},{"email":""}              |  
 +------------+--------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Thanks for your help,
Todd

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION()` return? The best answer depends on which version you use.

Comment: @bill "VERSION() 5.7.36-log". Thank you! I look forward to seeing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_tb where submission NOT like N'%"email": ""%';
```

This where condition check the gender not empty if you need to check null value. You can try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_tb where submission NOT like N'%"email": ""%' and submission NOT like N'%"email": ""%';
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you please update it so it checks the string length of the 'email' value of the JSON object in the submission column?

Comment: If you need to check the email is have exist value or not you can use the same query but the replace gender with the word email. It do the same

Answer (score 0):

Your description is no valid JSON, which you can test at jsonlint

This would only test if there is something that looks like a email, but with no accuracy if it really exists

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(13),
>   `submission` TEXT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `name`, `submission`)
> VALUES
>   ('13', 'Chris Sale', '[{"gender":"m"},{"email":"xyz@abc.com"}]'),
>   ('14', 'Amy Verlander', '[{"gender":"f"},{"email":"123@abc.com"}]'),
>   ('15', 'CC Sabathia', '[{"gender":"f"},{"email":""}]'),
>   ('16', 'Sonny Grey', '[{"gender":"m"},{"email":"nko@abc.com"}]'),
>   ('17', 'Jen Chapman', '[{"gender":"m"},{"email":""}]');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE submission->>"$[*].email"  NOT REGEXP '^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]{2,}$'
> ```

> ```
> id | name        | submission                   
> -: | :---------- | :----------------------------
> 15 | CC Sabathia | [{"gender":"f"},{"email":""}]
> 17 | Jen Chapman | [{"gender":"m"},{"email":""}]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9747a59b5a0249e3acb4df1a03ceeee3)*

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below and see if it helps

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(submission) > 1
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_char_length.asp

Comment: can you please update so the email value of submission is <1?